# "error TS1110: Type expected" when using export type

Tags: typescript, gruntjs

When trying to use `grunt-typescript` to compile my TS files, I'm getting the following error:

```
error TS1110: Type expected.
```

on each of these three lines

```
export type AttributeWriteType = "Append" | "Replace" | "Static";
export type Action = "Create" | "Delete";
export type Status = "Created" | "Queued" | "Running" | "Completed" | "Expired";
```

I'm fairly new to Typescript, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are those lines inside of a module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `grunt-typescript` isn't being supported anymore, so the TS compiler it uses is out of date.

I switched to using `grunt-ts` instead, and it is working as intended.

Answer (score 9):

This is caused by `grunt-typescript` having an out-of-date version of the TypeScript compiler. Check your package.json to ensure you're using a current version of the `typescript` package.

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering a similar error while was using `export type`. However, I was able to resolve this type error by upgrading my current typescript@^1.8.10, magically error disappeared.

If you are still currently running into this issue, what tsc/typescript version are you currently running?

Hopefully this can be helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was able to fix it by switching to `grunt-ts` instead of `grunt-typescript`. `grunt-ts` is using the latest version of typescript, so that fixed it.